# How to attach a HashMap to a Configuration object in Flink?

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I want to share a `HashMap` across every node in Flink and allow the nodes to update that HashMap. I have this code so far:

```
object ParallelStreams {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    //Is there a way to attach a HashMap to this config variable?
    val config = new Configuration()
    config.setClass("HashMap", Class[CustomGlobal])
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime)

    class CustomGlobal extends ExecutionConfig.GlobalJobParameters {
      override def toMap: util.Map[String, String] = {
        new HashMap[String, String]()
      }
    }

    class MyCoMap extends RichCoMapFunction[String, String, String] {
      var users: HashMap[String, String] = null
      //How do I get access the HashMap I attach to the global config here?
      override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
        super.open(parameters)
        val globalParams = getRuntimeContext.getExecutionConfig.getGlobalJobParameters
        val globalConf = globalParams[Configuration]
        val hashMap = globalConf.getClass

      }
      //Other functions to override here
    }
}
```

I was wondering if you can attach a custom object to the `config` variable created here `val config = new Configuration()`? (Please see comments in the code above).

I noticed you can only attach primitive values. I created a custom class that extends `ExecutionConfig.GlobalJobParameters` and attached that class by doing `config.setClass("HashMap", Class[CustomGlobal])` but I am not sure if that is how you are supposed to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common way to distribute parameters to operators is to have them as regular member variables in the function class. The function object that is created and assigned during plan construction is serialized and shipped to all workers. So you don't have to pass parameters via a configuration.

This would look as follows

```
class MyMapper(map: HashMap) extends MapFunction[String, String] {
 // class definition
}


val inStream: DataStream[String] = ???

val myHashMap: HashMap = ???
val myMapper: MyMapper = new MyMapper(myHashMap)
val mappedStream: DataStream[String] = inStream.map(myMapper)
```

The `myMapper` object is serialized (using Java serialization) and shipped for execution. So the type of `map` must implement the Java `Serializable` interface.

**EDIT:** I missed the part that you want the map to be updatable from all parallel tasks. That is not possible with Flink. You would have to either fully replicate the map and all updated (by broadcasting) or use an external system (key-value store) for that.

Comment: Another approach is to use a side-input.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45219889/3026310 for some pointers on that.