# Flink: join file with kafka stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a problem I don't really can figure out.
So I have a kafka stream that contains some data like this:

```
{"adId":"9001", "eventAction":"start", "eventType":"track", "eventValue":"", "timestamp":"1498118549550"}
```

And I want to replace 'adId' with another value 'bookingId'.
This value is located in a csv file, but I can't really figure out how to get it working.

Here is my mapping csv file:

```
9001;8
9002;10
```

So my output would ideally be something like

```
{"bookingId":"8", "eventAction":"start", "eventType":"track", "eventValue":"", "timestamp":"1498118549550"}
```

This file can get refreshed every hour at least once, so it should pick up changes to it.

I currently have this code which doesn't work for me:

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.enableCheckpointing(30000); // create a checkpoint every 30 seconds
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);

DataStream<String> adToBookingMapping = env.readTextFile(parameters.get("adToBookingMapping"));

DataStream<Tuple2<Integer,Integer>> input = adToBookingMapping.flatMap(new Tokenizer());

//Kafka Consumer
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", parameters.get("bootstrap.servers"));
properties.setProperty("group.id", parameters.get("group.id"));

FlinkKafkaConsumer010<ObjectNode> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<>(parameters.get("inbound_topic"), new JSONDeserializationSchema(), properties);

consumer.setStartFromGroupOffsets();

consumer.setCommitOffsetsOnCheckpoints(true);

DataStream<ObjectNode> logs = env.addSource(consumer);

DataStream<Tuple4<Integer,String,Integer,Float>> parsed = logs.flatMap(new Parser());

// output -> bookingId, action, impressions, sum
DataStream<Tuple4<Integer, String,Integer,Float>> joined = runWindowJoin(parsed, input, 3);


public static DataStream<Tuple4<Integer, String, Integer, Float>> runWindowJoin(DataStream<Tuple4<Integer, String, Integer, Float>> parsed,
      DataStream<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>> input,long windowSize) {

  return parsed.join(input)
          .where(new ParsedKey())
          .equalTo(new InputKey())
          .window(TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.of(windowSize, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
          //.window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(30000)))
          .apply(new JoinFunction<Tuple4<Integer, String, Integer, Float>, Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Tuple4<Integer, String, Integer, Float>>() {

              private static final long serialVersionUID = 4874139139788915879L;

              @Override
              public Tuple4<Integer, String, Integer, Float> join(
                              Tuple4<Integer, String, Integer, Float> first,
                              Tuple2<Integer, Integer> second) {
                  return new Tuple4<Integer, String, Integer, Float>(second.f1, first.f1, first.f2, first.f3);
              }
          });
}
```

The code only runs once and then stops, so it doesn't convert new entries in kafka using the csv file. Any ideas on how I could process the stream from Kafka with the latest values from my csv file?

Kind regards,

darkownage

Answer (score 4):

Your goal appears to be to join steaming data with a slow-changing catalog (i.e. a side-input).  I don't think the `join` operation is useful here because it doesn't store the catalog entries across windows.  Also, the text file is a bounded input whose lines are read once.

Consider using `connect` to create a connected stream, and store the catalog data as managed state to perform lookups into.   The operator's parallelism would need to be 1.

You may find a better solution by researching 'side inputs', looking at the solutions that people use today.   See [FLIP-17](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-17+Side+Inputs+for+DataStream+API) and [Dean Wampler's talk at Flink Forward](https://youtu.be/BzCEYGm1-e4?t=22m6s).